# How to reference OpenAPI operation description from an external file?

Tags: yaml, swagger, openapi, redocly

Is it possible to reference OpenAPI operation `description` from an external file?

Here is my sample code. I want to keep the description "**This API is used to get user details**" in a separate file and use it here like a variable or template or as a reference. Is there any way to do this?

```
 get:
  tags:
    - User
  summary: Get user details
  description:  This API is used to get user details
  operationId: updateUser
  parameters:
    - name: userid
      in: path
      description: The id that needs to be pulled
      required: true
      schema:
        type: string
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Redocly CLI to [bundle](https://redocly.com/docs/cli/commands/bundle/), then you can put it in a separate file like this:

```yaml
 get:
  tags:
    - User
  summary: Get user details
  description: 
    $ref: ./updateUser-description.md
  operationId: updateUser
  parameters:
    - name: userid
      in: path
      description: The id that needs to be pulled
      required: true
      schema:
        type: string
```

Then, in a separate file named `updateUser-description.md` (note, you could change the name too):

```
This API is used to get user details
```

Then, when you run the bundle command it resolves the $ref and replaces the description with the contents in that corresponding Markdown file.

```
npx @redocly/cli bundle my-openapi.yaml
```

Comment: Hi Domino, thanks for your quick response. But I'm getting this error when I use $ref like above. "Expected type `string` but got `object`.Redocly OpenAPI"

Comment: @jestges if you see this error in an editor (e.g. VS Code or Swagger Editor), that's expected because `$ref` usage in `description` is not standard OpenAPI syntax, it's  custom syntax that Redocly supports.

Comment: I have updated Domino response by adding a static description. Is it possible to have like this? Description 1 as a fixed text and other from a reference file? Please let me know if there is any way

Comment: @jestges no. That is invalid YAML and also an invalid proposal. However, there are different ways to accomplish that, it would involve writing some custom code.

Here is what you proposed (for historical context):

```yaml
  description: | "Description 1 here and description 2 from below ref"
    $ref: ./updateUser-description.md
```